# Gradle does not honor --add-modules jvm argument in JDK9

Tags: java, gradle, jvm, jvm-arguments, java-9

I am trying JDK9 (9-ea+143), and need to set `--add-modules java.xml.bind`. I have tried:

- Setting `GRADLE_OPTS="--add-modules java.xml.bind '-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=--add-modules java.xml.bind'"`
- Setting `org.gradle.jvmargs=--add-modules java.xml.bind` in gradle.properties.
- Adding `test { jvmArgs '--add-modules java.xml.bind' }` to build.gradle
- Adding `tasks.withType(Test) { jvmArgs '--add-modules java.xml.bind' }` to build.gradle
- Adding `tasks.withType(JavaExec) { jvmArgs '--add-modules java.xml.bind' }` to build.gradle

Tests still fail. What am I missing?

I have an example project in https://github.com/henrik242/gradle-jdk9-test-problem

```
✨  ./gradlew build
:compileJava
/foo/gradle-jdk9-test-problem/src/main/java/SomeClass.java:1: error: package javax.xml.bind does not exist
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationException;
                     ^
/foo/gradle-jdk9-test-problem/src/main/java/SomeClass.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
  public void doStuff() throws ValidationException {
                               ^
  symbol:   class ValidationException
  location: class SomeClass
/foo/gradle-jdk9-test-problem/src/main/java/SomeClass.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    throw new ValidationException("msg");
              ^
  symbol:   class ValidationException
  location: class SomeClass
3 errors
:compileJava FAILED
```

Answer (score 6):

It works when adding the following to build.gradle:

```
compileJava {
  options.compilerArgs += ["--add-modules", "java.xml.bind"]
}

compileTestJava {
  options.compilerArgs += ["--add-modules", "java.xml.bind"]
}

test {
  jvmArgs += ["--add-modules", "java.xml.bind"]
}
```

Is there an easier way?

EDIT: This also works:

```
tasks.withType(AbstractCompile) {
  options.compilerArgs += ["--add-modules", "java.xml.bind"]
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
  jvmArgs += ["--add-modules", "java.xml.bind"]
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me after one day of struggling with this issue. I wish there were a way to give you more points than 10 just for an upvote for this solution.