# mac java 9 gradle ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement when building

Tags: java, gradle

I'm trying to build a gradle project on Mac with Java 9, but I'm getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
```

Java version is:

```
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

How do I add JAXB to the classpath? This projects builds on Windows and other computers OK without adding JAXB.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing this because of changes in Java 9. Here's how to solve that: [How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j#43574427)

However, if your project is written for Java 8 (or older), what I would really suggest is letting Gradle know about that in your build.gradle:

```
...

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

...
```

Comment: I tried adding sourceCompatibility = 1.9 and targetCompatibility = 1.9 to my build.gradle, but it didn't help. I don't know where to put: --add-modules java.xml.bind in my build.gradle file. Can you be a little more specific on how to tell gradle to include the modules?

Comment: You have to set compatibility to 1.8 and NOT 1.9

Comment: This answers your question how to add the java arguments in gradle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530898/gradle-does-not-honor-add-modules-jvm-argument-in-jdk9#40533958

Comment: `--add-modules java.xml.bind` is a short term solution. The next phase, to remove the java.xml.bind module completely is already in draft form, see: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8189188

Answer (score 0):

It works when adding the following to build.gradle:

```
compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

tasks.withType(AbstractCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += ["--add-modules", "java.xml.bind"]
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs += ["--add-modules", "java.xml.bind"]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following under `dependencies` block to solve missing `JAXBElement`:

`runtime('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api')`